# TypeScript React project inconclusive bugs when compiling create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

This is a bit of an unusual question but I'm having frequent problems with the typescript compiler (or maybe webpack, or related).

This happens to me about twice a day (the error messages are different each time):

1.) I do normal code changes.
2.) I receive some weird inexplicable bug - the most recent was:

> Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

3. Obviously, there is no code at line 0 anywhere in my modules except for import statements. But I check my file for all kinds of `.map` statements and try to find the bug, restart the development server a couple of times meanwhile (same error).
4. Eventually, the bug mysteriously disappears - in this case, I just commented all my import statements and uncommented them shortly after without changing anything else (I did not accidentally fix the bug).

This is happening multiple times a day now. I was on Typescript 4.0.2, now I've downgraded to 3.9.7.

**Are there any ways to "reset" the compiler (e. g. delete temp files) that may solve this? I'm really not sure how to go about this.**

I'm using create-react-app with the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.14",
    "@types/redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.15.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-intl": "^5.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
```

**My tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `react-scripts` is using older versions of eslint. [follow issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9515) 
`@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0"`
 `@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0"`
**Note manually upgrading packages in project didn't work**

> `react-script` also gives peer dependency error

`react-scripts@3.4.3 requires a peer of typescript@^3.9.2 but typescript@^4.0.2 was installed.`
For now we can degrade to `typescript@^3.9.2` till the time `react-scripts` support `typescript@^4.0`

Comment: For those stumbling across this answer, it's mostly correct. Update your package.json to pin `typescript` to `^3` for the time being, and then delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Following that, `npm i` to reinstall node modules. Subsequently running `npm run start` should then work. If you have an interest in eventual typescript 4 support, subscribe to the linked GitHub issue here as well to get updates.